# Can't figure out why one of my assets is shiny?

Tags: mesh, objects, lighting

[image: A][image: B]

Hello, I'm new to modelling and have been making a few small tiles to snap together in unity. As you can see, Tile A has sides of the same color, with no strange lighting going on. Tile B's sides, however, appear to have different lighting. I've looked around and cant figure out how to make tile B look like tile A. Both of these files use the exact same options; B is a copy of A which I reconfigured into a bend.

Comment: set the [shading](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html#flat) to flat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: woot, flat flat]

The easiest way while you are in Object Mode is to switch to flat shading in the Tools panel. Alternatively you can add an Edge Split Modifier in the Properties Editor.